# Are these usages of LINQ's Find and Single methods with lambda expression are equal?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, lambda

I follow this tutorial: http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-music-store/mvc-music-store-part-4

The author uses Single method:

```
public ActionResult Browse(string genre)//AUTHOR'S CODE
{
    // Retrieve Genre and its Associated Albums from database
    var genreModel = storeDB.Genres.Include("Albums").Single(g => g.Name == genre);

    return View(genreModel);
}
```

and Find method:

```
public ActionResult Details(int id)//AUTHOR'S CODE
{
    var album = storeDB.Albums.Find(id);

    return View(album);
}
```

By analogy to `Browse()`(first example) method I wanted to use  Single method again so I wrote:

```
public ActionResult Details(int id) 
{ //MY CODE
    Album album = storeDB.Albums.Single(a => a.AlbumId == id);
    return View(album);
}
```

**Question:** Does `var album = storeDB.Albums.Find(id);` and `Album album = storeDB.Albums.Single(a => a.AlbumId == id);` works in different way? The result seems to be the same.

Comment: The "duplicate" does not refer to my question.

Comment: read the first answer, it covers the differences between Find and Single (among others)

Comment: @ken2k It does not refer to correctness of my lambda expression.

Comment: While in the case that you outlined everything will produce results that are effectively the same -- the underlying behavior of the two methods is significantly different.

Comment: You could always check the IL to find out if they do, in fact, work the same way.